# Font embedding problem with EPS figures in LaTeX

Tags: fonts, pdftex, eps, epstopdf

I have an EPS figure generated by Microsoft Visio with PDFCreator. I want to add this EPS figure to my document using `pdflatex` by declaring `\usepackage{epstopdf}` but the fonts in the EPS figure are not properly managed.

What's the best solution for adding EPS figures with properly embedded fonts?

Comment: Can you be moire specific about the problem? What output do you get, and what do you want to get?

Comment: i mean letters in the figure are blurred ..tell me a method to add eps figure with out using conversion of eps to pdf library..

Comment: Conversion to pdf should not blur the fonts. Can you make the original eps file and the pdf version available for download?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX, by the way.

Comment: You can make them available from anywhere, and edit your question to add links.

Comment: both eps and created pdf is upladed    https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_sDnLqHjQ1xb09iZVV4Z1RGYVU/edit?usp=sharing// https://docs.google.com/document/d/1NRRZKqhZ57zaLCjJz8OiIt3SAK41D1eurojGFwQWzCg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The eps file is bitmapped, which causes the blurring effect. It's difficult to know how this happened. One possibility is that the image has been stored using jpg, gif, png or another bitmap format at some stage of your workflow.

Comment: probelm is that i have drawn the figure using microsoft visio.It is not possible to save it as .eps.so I installed pdf converter to acheive this.tell me any other option to have .eps from visio.

Answer (score 1):

You need to export the file from Visio using a method that avoids bitmapping. I think the [MetafileToEPSConverter](http://wiki.lyx.org/Windows/MetafileToEPSConverter) is what you need. Note that vector graphics can be stored using either eps or pdf without distortion; the blurring effect that you are seeing probably results from the file being stored using a bitmap format (jpg, gif, png, etc.) at some stage of your workflow.